# Vector [] operation (read only) thread safety

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I have created a vector and filled data as part of an object initialization. The vector will not be modified after initialization. The declaration of the vector is

```
std::vector<AnalyticalChuckRing_t> m_analyticalRings;
```

We will call a method named `GroupCirclesByRing` from multiple async tasks. The following lines of code access the vector object in this method. I am almost sure that these statement does not need protection as it does not modify the object. Where can I find the documentation to ensure that thread synchronization is not required?

```
 auto GetRingAndAngle = [=](const CPoint& point)
            {
                double dDistance = DistanceFromOrigin(point);
                double dAngle{ 0.0 };
                for (int nRing = 1; nRing <= TotalRings; ++nRing)
                {
                    if (abs(dDistance - m_analyticalRings[nRing].dRadius) < 3 )
                    {
                        dAngle = atan2((resultRings[0][0].center.m_dY - point.m_dY), (point.m_dX - resultRings[0][0].center.m_dX));
                        // Convert angle to range [0 : 2 PI]
                        dAngle = (dAngle < 0) ? (2 * M_PI + dAngle) : dAngle;
                        return make_tuple(nRing, dAngle);
                    }
                }
                return make_tuple(InvalidRingNo, dAngle);
            };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition

Comment: i doubt you can find something that explicity states your code is ok. You can find rules for what is not ok, and they do not apply because nothing is written

Comment: My question is whether I have to protect the method GroupCirclesByRing  with a mutex

Comment: I understand what your question is. You need a mutex to protect from race conditions. Did you read the above link?

Comment: btw details do matter. It is possible to add code to your 2 lines that make them do something entirely different and actually modify the vector. Please include a [mcve] if you want to be sure that you get correct answers

Comment: I added the code. In the method i do not modify the vector.

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I find the documentation to ensure that thread synchronization is not required?

That would be the C++ standard. Drafts are publicly available at https://github.com/cplusplus/draft

Take a look at sections like [intro.races].